# textout.getText() is leading to a "may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'" message

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void one (View view){
        EditText textout=(EditText)findViewById (R.id.textView);
        Double amount = Double.parseDouble(**textout.getText()**.toString());
        Double amountOne= amount + 1;
        textout.setText(**amountOne.toString()**);

 }
```

The first issue is that the `getText()` method is leading to a

> may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException

message.

The second one is that `amountOne.toString()` is leading to a

> Number formatting does not take into account locale settings. Consider using String.format instead

Can someone help me with these issues?

Comment: Those are warnings from Android Studio. You can choose to do something about them or you can ignore them.

Comment: but the app is shutting down and not working

Comment: Okay, in that case, can you post the activity that's causing the issue and the stacktrace as well?

Comment: Sounds like the IDE is giving you good advice.  The concepts are not hard to understand, so I suggest searching each of those terms for further clarification.

Comment: problem solved( it wasn't related to the notes)

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code in the `onCreate()` method

```
 EditText textout = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `textout` is `null`:

```
if (textout != null) {
    textout.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%f", amountOne);
}
```

Use `%.1f` instead of `%f`, if you only want **1** decimal place. And `%.2f` for **2** decimal places, and so on.